# I can't insert values to mysql table using the shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I've been studying mysql in SHELL and I'm trying to insert values to a table using INSERT INTO....

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

The table I'm using:

[image]

And this is how I'm trying to insert the values:

```
INSERT INTO clients VALUES 
('Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria Dolores.95983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Adrian Fernandez','Adrian.55818851J@random.names','1970-04-09','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Maria Luisa Marin','Maria Luisa.83726282A@random.names','1957-07-30','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Pedro Sanchez','Pedro.78522059J@random.names','1992-01-31','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30');
```

Comment: Please define column name and after define value of equal column

Comment: Next time you ask a question post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` command instead of screenshot please.

Comment: PS. Your `created_at` field have default value (it is auto-utilized), but nevertheless you assign it a value directly. Are you sure it is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify 6 values for each record in VALUES clause dataset whereas table structure contains 8 fields.

You must specify 6 fields which value is specified in your query for:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, email, birthdate, gender, active, created_at)
VALUES 
('Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria Dolores.95983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Adrian Fernandez','Adrian.55818851J@random.names','1970-04-09','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Maria Luisa Marin','Maria Luisa.83726282A@random.names','1957-07-30','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Pedro Sanchez','Pedro.78522059J@random.names','1992-01-31','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30');
```

Alternatively you may specify "placeholder" values for the fields non-listed in VALUES clause. NULL or DEFAULT for autoincrement and DEFAULT for updated_at:

```
INSERT INTO clients 
VALUES 
(NULL,'Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria Dolores.95983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30',DEFAULT),
(NULL,'Adrian Fernandez','Adrian.55818851J@random.names','1970-04-09','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30',DEFAULT),
(NULL,'Maria Luisa Marin','Maria Luisa.83726282A@random.names','1957-07-30','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30',DEFAULT),
(NULL,'Pedro Sanchez','Pedro.78522059J@random.names','1992-01-31','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30',DEFAULT);
```

PS. I prefer the former method. The latter is affected by any table structure change, whereas the former may stay unchanged if you'll alter fields order in table structure or add NULLable fields into it.

Answer (score 3):

Add fields.

```sql
INSERT INTO clients (name, email, birthdate, gender, active, created_at) VALUES 
('Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria Dolores.95983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Adrian Fernandez','Adrian.55818851J@random.names','1970-04-09','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Maria Luisa Marin','Maria Luisa.83726282A@random.names','1957-07-30','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30'),
('Pedro Sanchez','Pedro.78522059J@random.names','1992-01-31','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30');
```

Answer (score 2):

You specified the `update_at` column with default value of `current_timestamp`, add `default` on your `insert` script for both auto increment field and `update_at` columns.

```
insert into clients values
(default, 'Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria Dolores.95983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30', default),
(default, 'Adrian Fernandez','Adrian.55818851J@random.names','1970-04-09','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30', default),
(default, 'Maria Luisa Marin','Maria Luisa.83726282A@random.names','1957-07-30','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30', default),
(default, 'Pedro Sanchez','Pedro.78522059J@random.names','1992-01-31','M',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30', default);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=zp273H8wlV) to test.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one help you :-

```
insert into clients(`name`,`email`,`birthdate`,`gender`,`active`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES
('Maria Dolores Gomez','Maria5983222J@random.names','1971-06-06','F',1,'2018-04-09 16:51:30','2018-04-09 16:51:30');
```

Comment: why did you decide that `updated_at` must be assigned the same value which is assigned to `created_at`?